# Getting minimum Int in IndexedSeq[(Int, Future[Long])] where Long > 0

Tags: scala, future

I have a scala `IndexedSeq[(Int, Future[Long])])`.

I would like to fill out this function:

```
def getMininumIfCountIsPositive(distances: IndexedSeq[(Int, Future[Long])]): Future[Option[Int]] = {

}
```

If there does not exist an element where the Long is greater than 0, should return a Future of None. If there are elements where the Long is greater than 0, should return a Future of the minimum associated Int.

This is what I've got right now:

```
Future.sequence(distances.map {
  case (index, count) => count.map(index -> _)
}) map {
  s =>
    Option(s.filter(_._2 > 0).minBy(_._1)._1)
}
```

But, I don't know how to handle the case where there are no elements that pass the filter, or where Futures have failed.

Comment: What if one of the `Future[Long]`s has failed?

Comment: @LimbSoup In that case, I would be fine just ignoring its associated Int, and not considering it in the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Map your sequence of Int, Future[Long] to a sequence of Future[(Int,Long)]:

```
val futureOfSequence = a map ( b: (Int, Future[Long]) => b._2 map ( c => (b._1,c)))
```

Then use `Future.sequence` to convert that sequence of Future[(Int,Long)] to Future[IndexedSeq(Int,Long)]

```
val sequenceOfFuture = Future.sequence(futureOfSequence)
```

Now you can map that Future to your Future[Option[Int]]:

```
val finalResult = sequenceOfFuture map ( iSeq: IndexedSeq[(Int,Long)] => /* your logic goes here */ )
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather long-winded..

```
def get(a: IndexedSeq[(Int, Future[Long])]): Future[Option[Int]] = {
    Future.sequence( // Convert the Seq[Future] to Future[Seq]
        a.map{ case (index, f) => 
            f.map(l => (index, l)) // map each Future to be paired with its index
                .recover{ case _: Throwable => (0, 0L)} // recover failed Futures as (0, 0) since they'll be thrown out anyway
        }
    ).map{ seq => 
        Option(seq.minBy(_._2)) // Map the Seq to it's minimum element wrapped in Option
            .filter(_._2 > 0)  // Remove non-positives
            .map(_._1)  // Take the index
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an efficient version, derived from the one in the question:

```
Future.traverse(distances) {
  case (index, count) => count.map(index -> _)
} map { _.foldLeft(None: Option[Int]) {
  case (a, (_, x)) if x <= 0 => a
  case (None, (i, _)) => Some(i)
  case (Some(ai), (i, _)) => Some(ai min i)
}}
```

`Future.traverse` lets us combine the `Future.sequence` and `map` operations together. The `foldLeft` combines all the logic from `filter` and `minBy` and produces the appropriate `Option`.

Both `Future.traverse` and `Future.sequence` produce a failed future if any of the futures they are built from fails, so you already have proper failure handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
trait Test2 {
  import scala.concurrent.Future
  import scala.concurrent.Future.{traverse, successful}

  implicit def context: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

  def logic(in: IndexedSeq[(Int, Long)]): Option[Int]

  def getMininumIfCountIsPositive(a: IndexedSeq[(Int, Future[Long])]): Future[Option[Int]] = {
    traverse(a) { case (i, f) => successful(i).zip(f) } map(logic)
  }
}
```